# Is there a way to make Python's console display docstrings nicely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, pycharm, docstring

Whenever I use iPython to ask for a docstring in the PyCharm console, it gives me something that looks like [image: this]. Is there an easy way to make it return beautiful, word-wrapped docstrings?

Comment: That's not what it's supposed to look like. There's probably something misconfigured somewhere.

Comment: What does your `ipython` show when run by itself (without PyCharm)? Mine shows proper formatting.

Comment: It looks normal, proper formatting - it's PyCharm specific