# PyCharm Python console displaying docstrings incorrectly

Tags: python, console, ipython, pycharm

The console in my PyCharm prints documentation incorrectly - it still has \n symbols in place of a new line, and only prints out a single long line. Does anybody know what the issue could be?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu5t9.jpg here is an image of what I'm describing.

Comment: A repeat of an unanswered question from a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937959/is-there-a-way-to-make-pythons-console-display-docstrings-nicely

Comment: Can you provide complete way of replicating your problem? i.e. show your imports and variable declaration

Comment: @nanotek -

It's nothing fancy. It's just

`import numpy as np
>
? np.array()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `print` function and the `__doc__` attribute to display the docstrings.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array.__doc__)

Create an array.
Parameters
----------
object : array_like
    An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose
    __array__ method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.
dtype : data-type, optional
    The desired data-type for the array.  If not given, then the type will
    be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the
...
```

Comment: Oh, that works pretty well. Although it's a workaround - it would be nice to be able to use the ipython ? commands - 

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really think of it as a workaround. Your question was how to get docstrings to print nicely and that's how you can view python docstrings nicely. If you wanted an answer specifically related to getting the ipython `?` operator to  print things differently, then it would be good to include that in your question. I'm not an ipython expert, but I looked into it slightly, and I couldn't find the solution you were looking for.